# Blue Highlighting / Focus Ring on Catalyst App

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, uikit, uikitformac

I'm currently in the process of porting my iOS app to macOS using Project Catalyst.

All of my text fields, text views and table views have a blue outline when active.

I've noticed it in Apple Catalyst apps (e.g. News) in recent betas so I'm hoping it's just a bug.

Has anyone found any way to remove it otherwise?

Comment: I have the same issue, asked around on Apple Dev Forum, not much response so far: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121280

UIKit started to adopt the focusRing APIs that macOS UI elements have by default (see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483261-focusringtype), but there is no public API yet to change the default behaviour.

Comment: Please don't remove this ring - this is important for accessibility + keyboard only users.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In swift you can do

```
extension UITextView {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    @objc(_focusRingType)
    var focusRingType: UInt {
        return 1 //NSFocusRingTypeNone
    }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: You could also add this to a subclass if you don't want the behavior to be global etc.

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks dude. This was driving me crazy! :D

Answer (score 13):

It helps to disable focus ring in all "view" classes in Catalyst

```
extension UIView {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    @objc(_focusRingType)
    var focusRingType: UInt {
        return 1 //NSFocusRingTypeNone
    }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: This worked for me - solved a problem of bar buttons having a weird highlight on UIToolbar on Catalyst

Comment: Is there an obj c equivalent for this?

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done without any code in Interface Builder for specific buttons, if that fits your needs.

In the identity inspector, just set the user-defined run-time attribute to 1 like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a private method `_setFocusRingType:` that appears to match the [NSView API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483261-focusringtype?language=objc). I was able to use that to eliminate the focus ring, though this may not pass app review.

Use this at your own risk:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_setFocusRingType:");
NSMethodSignature *signature = [self.textView methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setSelector:selector];
NSUInteger arg = 1; // NSFocusRingTypeNone
[invocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:2];
[invocation invokeWithTarget:self.textView];
```

Hopefully we get a real solution from Apple.

Comment: Thanks I’ll take a look at this. It looks like Apple has removed the focus ring for all UI elements apart from UITextViews - including in Apple Catalyst apps.

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement to Amerino's answer for greater flexibility and use in Storyboards:

```
@IBDesignable
class UITextViewCS: UITextView {
    @IBInspectable
    public var focusRing: UInt = 1 // 0-default, 1-None, 2-Exterior

    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    @objc(_focusRingType)
    var focusRingType: UInt {
        guard [0, 1, 2].contains(focusRing) else { return 0 }
        return focusRing
    }
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this - this is a focus indicator for accessibility and is important for keyboard-only users.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to change the colour to white instead of bright blue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed here hasn't worked for me in situations where pressing tab adds a blue rectangle around entire views. I've seen it happen for the whole page of a UIPageViewController, for the cells of a UITableView and more. The only solution I was able to use to fix this is to override the key press.

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
open override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    guard let key = presses.first?.key else { return }
    switch key.keyCode {
    case .keyboardTab: break
    default: super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
    }
}
#endif
```