# How to remove focus ring on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mac-catalyst

I'm developing an app bu using macCatalyst and supporting context menus when user has right clicked on a cell in a tableview.

When user opened the menu, the blue focus ring is also visible around the cell. I'm looking for a way to remove this ring.

I've already removed the ring around UITextField, UITextView controls by using the answer here:

[Blue Highlighting / Focus Ring on Catalyst App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577345/blue-highlighting-focus-ring-on-catalyst-app)

But this solution didn't work for UITableView or UITableViewCell even I used the same solution for these controls.